# Calling javascript method based on controller returned value

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, richfaces, el

I have two Javascript method out of which I want to call only one depending upon the value returned by `Controller`. Actually I wanted to hide `rich:popPannel` if `listSize > 0`
and if `listSize = 0` `rich:popPannel` should be there on focus
which JSF component shall I use which might help me in implementing this type of criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using `listSize` anywhere else in your code ? If not you can return a `boolean` depending upon the value of `listSize`, which you would be using to show or hide popupPanel.